# Change Soundcard Bit Depth and Sample Rate via Command Line in Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, audio, powershell, sound-card

Is there a tool, piece of Powershell or similar for changing the bit depth and sample rate of a sound card via the command line in Windows? e.g. a software solution, preferably already found inside Windows without manually interacting with the GUI?

To do this manually you have to go into Control Panel > Sound (or System > Sound > More Sound Settings) then find the playback or recording device, right-click and go to properties, then advanced and change the format there which is tedious for multiple cards needing to be changed at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a tool](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sound_volume_view.html#command_line) that will probably help you do what you are attempting to do.  It is free and written by [NirSoft](https://www.nirsoft.net/).  Look specifically at the `/SetDefaultFormat [Bits Per Sample] [Sample Rate - Hertz]` command line option.

It is *possible* that this can be accomplished through WMI but I am too lazy to go down that route and climb through all of the exposed sound classes.

Good luck.

Comment: The interaction with @Tetsujin was *not ok* but I begrudgingly helped you anyways.<br>
He was only trying to help you (for free).  Please try to be nice here as we are only here trying to help people.  Many people don't realize that a better solution can be found when we know ***why*** someone is trying to do what they are trying to do.

Comment: Actually, your attitude in this entire exchange just leaves me smiling at how you'll continue to do this completely unnecessary step, 5 times a day… now I'm out. Have fun.

Comment: It’s a shame he had to act up to try to mask not knowing the answer.